# How can I install vuex in a vue CLI project?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I install and create a project vue with VUE CLI.
I would like to add VUEX to add a store in my app.
But when I use:

```
npm install vuex --save-dev
```

I have errors:

> Could not resolve dependency:peer vue@"^2.0.0" from vuex@3.6.2 node_modules/vuex  vuex@"*" from the root project

How can I fix this?
Should I install vue in other way?

Comment: Maybe try just `vue add vuex`

Comment: You can aslo try it "npm install vuex"

Answer (score 7):

There are two ways to add vuex in Vue Cli Project

1 The following documentation can help you

```
npm install vuex
```

Another one is

```
vue add vuex
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have problems with the command line, you can also add vuex with the User Interface. Just type `vue ui` and install vuex under plugins tab in the browser window, which just opened (at port 8000)

Answer (score 0):

To install the latest version you can use:

npm install vuex@next --save

Answer (score -2):

As stated in the [documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/installation.html), the following command can help you:

```
yarn add vuex
```